# How Shortcut to accept Suggestion of Android Studio (Whit Photo)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

when Android Studio suggest to me in Yellow how the photo, what is the shortcut to accept, this image see all:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With reference to your image, the android studio is showing the type of value that the specified method can accept in yellow color. Not a value that could be selected.

Answer (score 0):

these are the `Android's Studio` [tips](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html). check them out.

try `Ctrl + Shift + Space` or `Ctrl + Space`

Comment: This answer is wrong. This gives the autocomplete window focus, but does not physically fill it in. You still must press enter. Tested in Android Studio v. 1.5.1 on Windows.